# Windows 8 App - Deserializing xml files?

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, deserialization

I know there's a lot of topic about xml serialization/deserialization here, and more on other sites, but I can't find anything working for me.

I'm actually working on a Windows 8 Store application, developed with C# and XAML. This application is supposed to work as a simple wiki app, so there's not a lot of code to do. But there's a lot of information that I have to put in this app. So I chose this : The user choose what he wants with buttons, and no matter which button he clicked, it navigates to the same page, but this page must show informations from a xml file. This is better than create tons of pages, I think. I actually can get the button the user clicked, so I can select the good file to open.

But actually I never used XML serialization, so I don't know what to do.

So, I'm looking for the best/easiest way to deserialize pre-made xml files. The page never serialize anything, and the user can't modify a file. This is just like a getter. All the app needs to do is open the xml file and put informations in textblocks.

Thanks in advance for your help, i'm a little confused to ask it like that, but that's all I can do now :/

Comment: Msdn has [TONS of information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh.aspx) on this

Comment: Already looked there. Not working. My VS2012 even don't know what is FileStream. And yes, System.IO is in my using statements. That's why I'm here :/

Comment: Are you using the client version of the .Net?  Check your project properties, and change it to the full version of .Net 4 or 4.5

Comment: Is this change made in the "Targeted framework" section ? Because it's grey, I can't change this parameter. But when I created the project, I chose .NET 4.5 and Empty App in the Windows Store section.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand you want to know how to serialize and/or deserialize from a XML file. Here is some working code from a Windows Store App.

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
```

namespace Runner
{
    public static class SerializationHelper
    {
        public static void Save(Schedule shedule)
        {
            using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            using (var fileStream = store.CreateFile("Schedule.xml"))
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
            {
                var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Schedule));
                ser.Serialize(writer, shedule);
                writer.Close();
            }
        }

`public static Schedule Load()
    {
        var shcedule = new Schedule();
        using (var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (storage.FileExists("Schedule.xml"))
            {
                using (var stream = storage.OpenFile("Schedule.xml", FileMode.Open))
                {
                    var xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Schedule));
                    shcedule = xml.Deserialize(stream) as Schedule;
                    stream.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        return shcedule;
    }
}`

}

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, but it evidently doesn't deserialize in windows 10. I was better off just crawling webpages every time than trying to save the data.

```
public static async Task<T> ReadObjectFromXmlFileAsync<T>(string filename)
    {

        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();
        // this reads XML content from a file ("filename") and returns an object  from the XML
        T objectFromXml = default(T);
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(filename);
        Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
        objectFromXml = (T)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
        stream.Dispose();
        timer.Stop();
        double time = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        return objectFromXml;
    }

    public static async Task SaveObjectToXml<T>(T objectToSave, string filename)
    {
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();
        // stores an object in XML format in file called 'filename'
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();

        using (stream)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(stream, objectToSave);
        }
        timer.Stop();
        double time = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Connection.Downloaded();
    }

}
```

Then just bind your view to whatever class is storing the data...